# HTTP POST in Javascript with Chunked Uploads through generator

Tags: javascript, http, chunked-encoding

I'm trying to send an HTTP POST request to a server with the data file uploaded with chunked-transfer encoding.  Looking at the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/n7psA/), it seems like each chunk is actually its own separate XmlHTTPRequest.  Is that correct?

Furthermore, I'd like to be able to use a source that is a generator function, instead of a blob or a file (as the data is being created on-the-fly in the browser).  Can I modify the source like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6p54autn/) and just pass the generator function name instead of the blob?

```
function* gen() 
{ 
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

xhr.send(gen());
```

Comment: That fiddle simply sets some chunk variables to handle the loading div, they have no impact on the `xhr` request itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the code you posted is posting the data to the server in chunks by making multiple calls to XmlHTTPRequest from the function triggered on the "change" event listener.

Unfortunately I can't see any difference between your code and the version that you've based your version upon. Here's an example to do what you're requesting.

```
function chunkUploader(fn) {
    var iterator = fn();
    var chunk = iterator.next();
    while (!chunk.done) {
        upload(chunk);
        chunk = iterator.next();
    }
}
```

You should be able to call this with your function like so.

```
chunkUploader(gen);
```